# Good homebrewing podcasts?

Tags: first-time-brewer, brewing, media

Does any one have suggestions on podcasts about homebrewing? Preferably a short excerpt about what topics they bring up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Basic Brewing Radio

> Basic brewing, Interviews Gravity, Malts, Equipment, Quality, Everything

http://www.basicbrewing.com/index.php?page=radio

Episodes: 50+

#### Brew Strong

> Water treatment, Interviews, Mead

http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/category/shows/brewstrong/

Episodes: 50+

#### The Jamil Show

> Recieps, Brewing

http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/category/shows/jamilshow/

Episodes: 50+

#### Brewing TV

> Interviews, Brewing

http://brewingtv.com/

Episodes:

#### Experimental Homebrewing

> Experimental brewing

http://www.experimentalbrew.com/

Episodes: 5+

#### The Perfect Pour Craft Beer Podcast

> Craft beer

http://theperfectpour.podbean.com/category/craft-beer-podcasts/

Episodes: 100+

#### Craft beer academy

> Craftbeer

http://craftbeeracademy.com/category/podcast/
Episodes: 20+

Here are some more:
http://microbrewr.com/best-craft-beer-podcasts/

Answer (score 10):

[Brewing Network](http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/) should be your starting point. Download The Jamil Show, Brew Strong and Brewing With Style and listen to everything from the start. Yes, it is a LOT of podcasts, but you will learn so many things! There are other podcasts on the network, but I will recommend those to start with.
Topics: EVERYTHING. They cover all topics, from very basic to the very advanced. They chat with home brewers and pro brewers and random people in between. 
Warning: The shows may contain foul humor/language. Some content may not be family safe.

[Basic Brewing Radio](http://www.basicbrewing.com/index.php?page=radio) is the other podcast that you should download and listen to from the start.
Topics: EVERYTHING! Very similar to the podcast above, but more "professional" and family friendly.

Tip: Listen to the podcasts on 1.5 speed, then you get through them in a shorter time.

Happy listening!

Answer (score 5):

Beer smith is nice, that created of the software with the same name interviews different beer experts.

Comment: Cool I just found that one myself on acast but I havent listned to it.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend Experimental Homebrewing

Comment: Thanks!  we just released Episode 58.  We also have a shorter podcast called The Brew Files.  You can find them both at www.experimentalbrew.com

Answer (score 2):

**BRÜLOSOPHY**

20 Episodes [brulosophy.com](http://brulosophy.com)

Relatively new podcast where they recap "exbeeriments" they've done.  Essentially, they brew side-by-side batches, one control and one with a test variable.  The topics are pretty on point for homebrewers--it doesn't stray off topic like many other podcasts.

---

All-time favorite is **Basic Brewing**.  The Mr. Rodger of homebrew.  Can't get enough.

Answer (score 1):

Beer smith or American Home brewer Association is a great place to start.

Comment: The AHA does a podcast?

Answer (score 0):

Come and Brew It Radio

On iTunes and Stitcher

90+ episodes

FB: https://www.facebook.com/comeandbrewitradio/